# How to set eshell's ls command to different program in different OS?

Tags: microsoft-windows, eshell, linux, aliases

Since result of `/usr/bin/ls` is more neat compares with `eshell/ls` when filenames contain non-lattin Unicodes. I add an alias in `~/.emacs.d/eshell/alias`, which makes eshell use `/usr/bin/ls` as default:
`alias ls /usr/bin/ls $*`.
But this can only apply to Linux/Unix system, how can I make eshell know when it's Windows use `eshell/ls` as default `ls` command?